# Problem with save method overriding attribute value

Tags: django, model, init

I have a model called 'Trip' with a Foreign Key to 'Destination'. The Destination model specifies a maximum number of passengers in it's 'max_passengers' attribute.

**Trip**

```
class Trip(models.Model):

    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Destination,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="trips",
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    seats_available = models.IntegerField(
        null=False, blank=False, editable=False
    )
    trip_ref = models.CharField(
        max_length=32, null=True, editable=True, blank=True
    )
```

**Destination**

```
class Destination(Product):

    max_passengers = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    addons = models.ManyToManyField(AddOn)
    min_medical_threshold = models.IntegerField(
        default=0, null=False, blank=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Back in the Trip model, I am overriding the model save method, so that when a trip object is created, the 'seats_available' for that instance is set to the 'max_passengers' of the related destination:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.trip_ref:
        date = (self.date).strftime("%m%d-%y")
        self.trip_ref = self.destination.pk + "-" + date

    if not self.seats_available:
        self.seats_available = self.destination.max_passengers
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have additional models for Bookings and Passengers. When a booking is created, a post_save signal is sent, calling the model method on my Trips model, `def update_seats_avaialable()`:

```
def update_seats_available(self):

    reservations = (
        self.bookings.aggregate(num_passengers=Count("passengers"))
        ["num_passengers"]
    )
    self.seats_available = self.destination.max_passengers - reservations
    self.save() <---- PROBLEM
```

THe problem is when all seats are finally taken ie. the passenger count = max_passengers and seats availabe = 0. When self.save triggers the save method, `if not self.seats_available` = true and so this line of code is run: `self.seats_available = self.destination.max_passengers` which sets the seats available back to where it started. Is there another way of initialising the model object? My understanding is **init** method isnt advised...

Comment: You could add a `self.id` check on the `.save` overwrite. Thus `if not self.id and not self.seats_available:`. As an object has no id set till saved.

Comment: Does the post_save signal and the self.save() cause a save loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I came up with a solution:

```
def update_seats_available(self):

    reservations = (
        self.bookings.aggregate(num_passengers=Count("passengers"))
        ["num_passengers"])
    self.save(reservations=reservations)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):


    if not self.trip_ref:
        date = (self.date).strftime("%m%d-%y")
        self.trip_ref = self.destination.pk + "-" + date

    reservations = kwargs.pop('reservations', 0)
    self.seats_available = self.destination.max_passengers - reservations
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here I'm passing the value of reservation to the save method and doing the calculation there instead.